# button to send email with two attachment in ms access 2010

Tags: sql, email, vba, ms-access

I have a database in which i want to create a button which will send email with two attachments
from outlook. Paths to Files can be given. and it should give a popup like the form you get when you create a new mail to check if the body in the mail is correct?

Any idea how to achieve this?

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
'Arvin Meyer 03/12/1999
'Updated 7/21/2001
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = "info@datastrat.com"
    .Subject = "Look at this sample attachment"
    .body = "The body doesn't matter, just the attachment"
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Test.htm"
    '.attachments.Add "c:\Path\to\the\next\file.txt"
    .Send
    '.ReadReceiptRequested
End With

Exit_Here:
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
Resume Exit_Here

End Sub
```

Comment: You do this by writing some VBA code. How about you show your attempt?

Comment: I used some code but it directly sends the email with no popup check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jt5qg/

Comment: I am not sure about the details of the objects you are using, but If you want the user to review the mail, you should not probably call `.Send`. You can probably show (or any such equivalent) and then let the user send the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!!!! Thanks to ryadavilli

Instead of .send it was .Display

and it worked